# How to deploy files from different Git branches to different folders on the server?

Tags: git

I am looking for some directions for a proper Git setup for production/development environment for a PHP project. I'm trying to create one and I'm kind of stuck with how to do it right, even after days of searching for an answer.

I've got:

1. IDE (NetBeans)
2. Production server
3. Subdomain on the same server which I would like to use for development purposes. I know it may be not the best solution, but at least for now it could work, later I am planning to move it to another server.

On the server there is Git installed, same as on my client machine. I've got two branches - dev and production. The plan was to test everything on dev branch, then merge the branches and deploy it to production.

However, I can't find it anywhere how to use Git properly in this setup. I am pushing the branch to the repository at the server, then I was going to deploy the files to particular folder, depending on the branch (dev or prod).

I am performing this:

```
git clone --shared --branch dev myproject.git /var/www/vhosts/dev.mydomain.com/httpdocs/
rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/dev.mydomain.com/httpdocs/.git
```

It works for the first time, when the folder is empty, but git doesn't allow cloning to the folder when there are already files in it. Of course, I can remove everything from the folder, but it doesn't seem right, especially on the production server.

So the main question is - how do I update only files that have been modified without touching the rest? Or maybe I am doing it all wrong and it should work completely different? I've read the git manual and plenty of other websites dedicated to git, but it's either I'm too stupid or there's no answer to this question there.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have set up two different branches (`dev`, `prod`) of the same repo:

```
git clone --shared --branch dev myproject.git /var/www/vhosts/dev.mydomain.com/httpdocs/
git clone --shared --branch prod myproject.git /var/www/vhosts/prod.mydomain.com/httpdocs/
```

You can easily update the folder without removing it by pulling each directory:

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/dev.mydomain.com/httpdocs/ && git pull
cd /var/www/vhosts/prod.mydomain.com/httpdocs/ && git pull
```

Just make sure that you don't have files within your repo that would overwrite your local changes. One example of this would be a config file. You should create a config file `config.ini.example` that is managed by git and then add the line `config.ini` to the `.gitignore` file in the same folder, so your local config is not managed by git.

As a side note it is advisable from a security perspective to have different physical machines serving the development and production versions of your service. You should aim for this, if your resources allow it.